# defined loss function in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, loss

In my project, the negative instance is far more than positive instance, so I want to give positive instance with a larger weight. 
my target is:

```
loss = 0.0
if y_label==1:loss += 100 * cross_entropy
else:loss += cross_entropy
```

How to realizate this in tensorflow[?]

Answer (score 1):

Let `losses` to be a vector (rank-1 tensor) of loss values for the examples in your batch. And let `y` be the the vector of corresponding labels. You could then achieve the result you want by

```
weights = w_pos*y + w_neg*(1.0-y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(weights*losses)
```

Here, `w_pos` and `w_neg` are constant scalar values (`w_pos=100.0` and `w_neg=1.0` in your example). The vector `weights` then has a value of `w_pos` for examples where the label equals 1 and `w_neg` where it equals 0. You then multiply `weights` element-wise with `losses` to weigh the values in the `losses` according to the corresponding labels and then take the mean.