# Custom Loss Function in TensorFlow for weighting training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to weight the training data based on a column in the training data set. Thereby giving more importance to certain training items than others. The weighting column should not be included as a feature for the input layer.

The Tensorflow documentation holds an [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.losses) how to use the label of the item to assign a custom loss and thereby assigning weight:

```
# Ensures that the loss for examples whose ground truth class is `3` is 5x
# higher than the loss for all other examples.
weight = tf.multiply(4, tf.cast(tf.equal(labels, 3), tf.float32)) + 1

onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes=5)
tf.contrib.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, onehot_labels, weight=weight)
```

I am using this in a custom **DNN** with three hidden layers. In theory i simply need to replace **labels** in the example above with a tensor containing the weight column.

I am aware that there are several threads that already discuss similar problems e.g. [defined loss function in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273677/defined-loss-function-in-tensorflow)

For some reason i am running into a lot of problems trying to bring my weight column in. It's probably two easy lines of code or maybe there is an easier way to achieve the same result.

Comment: What problems? You should describe them and include relevant error messages.

Comment: I think i found a solution. The problem is, that the weights i have created that  they do not match the feature tensorflow:

ValueError: weights can not be broadcast to values. Mismatch at dim 0. values.shape=[3] weights.shape=[120].

ValueError: Tensor("add:0", shape=(120,), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("fully_connected/BiasAdd:0", shape=(120, 3), dtype=float32).

Answer (score 1):

I believe i found the answer:

```
  weight_tf = tf.range(features.get_shape()[0]-1, features.get_shape()[0])
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(target, logits, weights=weight_tf)
```

The weight is the last column in the features tensorflow.

Comment: Is there a way to weight them differently depending on whether a cross entropy is matching or not?